# '$' is undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Trying to use a jQuery plugin and it is not working and this error

> '$' is undefined

keeps popping up. I am very new to Javascript and jQuery so please be as simple as possible

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="wpscripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script> 
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script src="thumb-images/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js"></script>
<script>DD_belatedPNG.fix('#preview_inner div a');</script>
<![endif]--> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var outer = $("#preview_outer");
        var arrow = $("#arrow");
        var thumbs = $("#thumbs span");
        var preview_pos;
        var preview_els = $("#preview_inner div");
        var image_width = preview_els.eq(0).width();
        thumbs.click(function () {
            preview_pos = preview_els.eq(thumbs.index(this)).position();
            outer.stop().animate({ 'scrollLeft': preview_pos.left }, 500);
            arrow.stop().animate({ 'left': $(this).position().left }, 500);
        });
        arrow.css({ 'left': thumbs.eq(0).position().left }).show();
        outer.animate({ 'scrollLeft': 0 }, 0);
        $("#preview_inner").css('width', preview_els.length * image_width);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Verify jquery is loading with a browser debugging tool or fiddler.

Comment: this means the jQuery library is not loaded correctly. Check you path, or even better, use something like this: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Do as Gabe suggested, it might be that your script src should be relative to the root of the site for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your script source path. It's likely not loading in.

If it's at the root of a site use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wpscripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

I see you have also tagged ASP.NET, so If it's in a control or somewhere that can be different for each page load, then use the following to have .Net figure out the actual relative path.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/wpscripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js") %>"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

That usually means that you have to import jquery at the top like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit**: Here is the link for the updated version. I believe that this page will always update to the latest version of jQuery whereas my above answer won't: [HERE](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=fr#jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using WordPress.
You often are not able to define links with a relative path.
try using the php function "get_theme_root();" to get the theme root and navigate from there